# Coins to be put in empty purses

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

There are six empty purses on the table. What is the number of ways to put 12 identical 1 rupee coin in purse such that at most one purse remains empty.

The way I did is

Case 1: No purse remains empty.
In that case the answer should be $\binom{11}{5}$

Case 2: One purse remains empty.
In this case answer should be 
$6\cdot \binom{11}{4}$

So the answer should be 
$\binom{11}{5} + 6\cdot \binom{11}{4}$

But the answer given is 
$\binom{12}{5} + 6\cdot \binom{11}{4}$

I believe the answer is wrong.
Kindly verify.

Comment: I understood the concept

Comment: $\binom{11}{5} + 6\cdot \binom{11}{4}$ = $\binom{11}{5} + \binom{11}{4}$ +5\cdot \binom{11}{4}$

Comment: Right, it should $(6)$ times, not $(5)$ times (i.e., choose the empty purse). With that edit, your answer is correct.